# Python & pygame can't be installed

Tags: python, pygame

I have tried (many, many, many) times now, installing pygame on my Mac (using brewer) but it always comes back with "No such file in directory". Then i tried installing python 2.7 via brewer, and the same error was output again. I  am using OSX El Capitan 10.11.

What can be the cause for this? I am by no means a genius with using the terminal, so i (now) assume that's where i f'ed up at some point.

It would really help if you could guide me through the installation process.

Thank you so much.

Comment: It's basically impossible to troubleshoot unless you post your commands and the error codes exactly as printed in the terminal.

Comment: This is when i try to pip install pygame pip install pygame
-bash: /usr/local/bin/pip: /usr/local/opt/python/bin/python2.7: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just installed pygame in OSX El Capitan. I had a similar problem. Did you install x-code developer tools? Also, two extremely straight forward directions I found were:

http://www.alexsilcock.net/notes/installing-python-3-pygame-and-pyopengl-on-mac-os-x-el-capitan/

http://kidscancode.org/blog/2015/09/pygame_install/

The first one is based off the second one. Kidscancode goes over how to install homebrew, cask, and everything you need. I hope this helped :).

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

Why are you installing python with brew? Why not install it with pip? 
 
`pip install hg+http://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame`